# Why does gradlew return cannot find symbol error when compiling code?

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew, cannot-find-symbol

I'm compiling a Minecraft mod with gradlew which I coded using Eclipse. The Minecraft mod uses an API which I have created previously. The problem is that when I'm trying to compile the mod with gradlew it gives me the error: "cannot find symbol".

The curious thing is now that when I'm moving the called function to a fresh class it does not give me the compilation error and everything is fine (I did not rename the function or changed anything in it I just moved it to a class where no other functions are in). Why is that? I would like to keep the function in the main class and not move it to a own class.

This is the method I'm using which gives me the error below:

```java
public static void RegisterSlabBlock(Block slabBlock, Block doubleSlabBlock, Class ItemBlockSlab, String completeName, String slabBlockName, String doubleSlabBlockName, String ModID) {
        try {
            GameRegistry.registerBlock(slabBlock, ItemBlockSlab, slabBlockName, slabBlock, doubleSlabBlock, false);
            GameRegistry.registerBlock(doubleSlabBlock, ItemBlockSlab,doubleSlabBlockName,slabBlock,doubleSlabBlock, true);
            SetLSCount.increaseBlockCount(1);
            DebugHelper.sendDebugInformation(slabBlock.toString(), 2, ModID, 5);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorHelper.AddError("Failed to register block: " + completeName + "; Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
```

The error in gradlew:

```
D:\Userdata\Louis\Dokumente\Programmieren\Forge Modding\1.8.9\Workspace - Trekcraft\build\sources\main\java\com\wix\lmh01\trekcraft\util\RegisterContent.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
                        RegisterHelper.RegisterBlockSlab(VariablesManager.block_warp_core_half_slab, VariablesManager.block_warp_core_double_slab, ItemBlockWarpCoreSlab.class, "block_warp_core_slab", "block_warp_core_half_slab", "block_warp_core_double_slab", Refrences.MODID);
                                      ^
  symbol:   method RegisterBlockSlab(Block,Block,Class<ItemBlockWarpCoreSlab>,String,String,String,String)
  location: class RegisterHelper
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
1 warning
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The ^ points to the dot after RegisterHelper.
The line I call this function with:

```java
RegisterHelper.RegisterSlabBlock(VariablesManager.block_warp_core_half_slab, VariablesManager.block_warp_core_double_slab, ItemBlockWarpCoreSlab.class, "block_warp_core_slab", "block_warp_core_half_slab", "block_warp_core_double_slab", Refrences.MODID);
```

The line I call the function with from the other class

```java
RegisterHelperBlocks.RegisterSlabBlock(VariablesManager.block_warp_core_half_slab, VariablesManager.block_warp_core_double_slab, ItemBlockWarpCoreSlab.class, "block_warp_core_slab", "block_warp_core_half_slab", "block_warp_core_double_slab", Refrences.MODID);
```

So it seams like something is wrong with the way I call the function with. It should normally work in booth ways I think.

Comment: Did you turn on "build automatically" in Eclipse? Under "Project>Build automatically"

Comment: @Daniele yes, i have build automatically on in Eclipse.